# Fancy Indexing vs Views in Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm confused by another part of the article in the attached link:

https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html

In the section "But fancy indexing does seem to return views sometimes, doesn't it?"

First idiom:

```
a = np.arange(10)
a[[1,2]] = 100
a
#array([  0, 100, 100,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9])
```

Second Idiom:

```
a = numpy.arange(10)
c1 = a[[1,2]]
c1[:] = 100
a
#array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> c1
#array([100, 100])
```

I'm still a bit confused as to how the first idiom is able to make the changes?

They explain that the first idiom is not calling **getitem** before **setitem** but why is it not doing it?

I thought that all fancy indexes returned a copy of the data rather than a view irrespective of the idiom used?

Although fancy indexing does not create a view as they demonstrate, as it still gives the desired result is it still considered good practice to use it as shown in idiom 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the way Python works.

The first statement calls the `setitem` method, the second `getitem`. The first one doesn't create a new object, but the second will (for fancy indexing, it will create a view for regular indexing).

And of course, we want this behavior so that we can set some values in an array that are not "regular" and where a view would not work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this fully yet. It seems there is more to it that just the idiom? Look at the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968814/fanccy-indexing-vs-view-in-numpy-part-ii

Comment: That's because it's not just one call to `setitem`, there are two indexing, one is get, creating a new array, the other one is set.

Comment: Tnx can you break break it down some more? What are the exact sequence of __setitem__, __getitem__ for each example?

Comment: If you have two [] on the same statement, the first is a get, the second is the set. First you retrieve some data from the array, whether a view or a copy, then you set the value with the right side of the assignment.

Comment: OK so in the example: a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4), ifancy = [0,2]. islice = slice(0,3,2). The two expressions are a[islice, :][:, ifancy] = 100 vs a[ifancy, :][:, islice] = 100. Here the total number of [] and slices is the same for both expressions, the only difference is that islice and ifancy are reversed in the second statement. Can you please break this example down, when I understand that I think I will understand everything.

Comment: Both times, the last slice is the setitem. Both time the first one is a get item. The first expression first creates a view, then calls set on the view, modifying the original array. The second time, you copy the data, then call set, modifying the copied data and not the original.

Comment: Think I (finally) getting it! The a[][] is the __setitem__ i.e. it is the "last slice" that you refer to (and is the same for both expressions).

Comment: The first slice in the first example uses islice, : and so it is a view. The first slice in the other expression is ifancy,: therefore it creates a copy. Where first here defers to the fact that they are the indexes of the a[][]. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: I think you got it yes 