# Fanccy Indexing vs View in Numpy part II

Tags: python, numpy

[Fancy Indexing vs Views in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52967957/fancy-indexing-vs-views-in-numpy)

In an answer to this equation: is is explained that different idioms will produce different results.

Using the idiom where fancy indexing is to chose the values and said values are set to a new value in the same line means that the values in the original object will be changed in place.

However the final example below:

https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html

"A final exercise"

The example appears to use the same idiom:

a[x, :][:, y] = 100

but it still produces a different result depending on whether x is a slice or a fancy index (see below):

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
ifancy = [0,2]
islice = slice(0,3,2)
a[islice, :][:, ifancy] = 100
a
#array([[100,   1, 100,   3],
#       [  4,   5,   6,   7],
#       [100,   9, 100,  11]])

a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
ifancy = [0,2]
islice = slice(0,3,2)
a[ifancy, :][:, islice] = 100  # note that ifancy and islice are interchanged here
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

My intuition is that if the first set of fancy indexes is a slice it treats the object like a view and therefore the values in the orignal object are changed.

Whereas in the second case the first set of fancy indexes is itself a fancy index so it treats the object as a fancy index creating a copy of the original object. This then means that the original object is not changed when the values of the copy object are changed.

Is my intuition correct?

The example hints that one should think of the sqeuence of **getitem** and **setitem** can someone explain it to my properly in theis way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python evaluates each set of [] separately.  `a[x, :][:, y] = 100` is 2 operations.

```
temp = a[x,:]           # getitem step
temp[:,y] = 100         # setitem step
```

Whether the 2nd line ends up modifying `a` depends on whether `temp` is a view or copy.

Remember, `numpy` is an addon to Python.  It does not modify basic Python syntax or interpretation.